# stunnel changes https pages to http when clicking a link

Tags: server, apache2, websites, https

I have stunnel4 installed on Ubuntu Server 11.10. I have apache installed from the repositories. I have some programs installed such as ownCloud or sitebar. When I visit their web pages over the Internet using addresses like https://myserver.com/owncloud, if I then click on a link within the web page that appears, it takes me to a http address such as http://myserver.com/owncloud/linkiclickedon and the page appears white.

I have to always keep changing the URLs to https. How can I correct this behaviour?

Th site installed on the server is located at for example, http://myserver/owncloud, but I am taking it through stunnel to give it some security when accessing it online.

Comment: From its description it looks like that `stunnel4` encrypts traffic between the server and client, without touching the actual contents of the message (i.e. rewriting URLs from http -> https). Can't you create a proper setup with SSL for Apache?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. Apache documentation on Ubuntu says "The default HTTPS configuration will use a certificate and key generated by the ssl-cert package. They are good for testing, but the auto-generated certificate and key should be replaced by a certificate specific to the site or server". Is it therefore not safe for me to just use the key that comes with or is generated by it?

Comment: Thank you, you have answered my question, this is exactly what I need. But I can't mark as answer. If you can Answer it using button below I will mark it answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of the `stunnel4` package, it looks like that the application just acts as a secured messenger: at the server side data is encrypted, at the client side it's unencrypted without touching the message contents itself (like rewriting http:// URLs to https://). Since you control the Apache server, you are recommended to configure SSL on Apache. For example, see [How to easily deploy HTTPS in ubuntu 10.04?](https://superuser.com/q/310879/47108)